# Working on GitHub, confused about pull requests and avoiding conflicts

Tags: git, github

Often when I fork a repo, work on it, and submit a pull request, there are conflicts. I'm not sure how to deal with those. Am I supposed to do a `git pull upstream/master` on my end before pushing to my fork, and then subsequently doing a PR? Am I supposed to do a rebase at some point, too, to squash my commits? Which rebase command do I use for that, the interactive version? What about using the trick `git reset --soft <commit>` followed by `git commit`?

I'm just confused about at what point to do these things, and if I need to do them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When submitting a PR, you generally want to make sure your changes are based on the most recent version of a branch, which you can accomplish using the `git rebase` command.

Assuming you are making your changes on a "feature" branch (that is, a branch that you have created locally expressly for the purpose of the pull request -- adding a feature, fixing a bug, etc), you would so something like this, assuming you were basing your changes on the `master` branch:

```
# ensure the master branch is up-to-date
git checkout master
git pull

# rebase your PR
git checkout my-branch
git rebase master
```

If you are *not* working on a feature branch, @hek2mgl's suggestion (`git pull --rebase master`) will work, but I highly recommend using feature branches to isolate your changes from the upstream development.

This will ensure that your changes will apply without conflicts.  You may need to resolve some conflicts locally as part of the rebase operation.

It is not necessary to squash your commits, but it is often helpful, especially if you have commits that are along the lines of "fixed a typo" or "forgot a semicolon".  Some projects will ask you to limit PRs to a single commit, in which case it *will* be necessary to squash your commits.

Comment: Again, I really like your avatar! :D But the plus one is for mentioning feature branches and how to deal with them.

Comment: Thanks! But this looks like it's pulling from my own fork. Wouldn't I have to do `git pull upstream master`?

Comment: It depends on what your remotes are named!  I often have `origin` set to the upstream, and then a remote named `larsks` for my own copy of the repository.  So feel free to `s/origin/whatever_you_call_the_upstream_remote/` in the above.

Comment: @larsks Ok. Just so I'm clear: if I forked from steve/webthing into csj/webthing and cloned that, and my origin is set to csj/webthing and upstream is steve/webthing, then the steps would be (assuming I'm working on the master branch): `git pull upstream master; git rebase upstream/master` correct?

Comment: Depending on your git configuration, `git pull upstream master` may just make life difficult.  Consider instead `git fetch upstream master; git rebase upstream/master` (the `fetch` command updates the remote repository state in your local repository without attempting to make any changes to your local working copy).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do a:

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

to pull upstream changes. The `--rebase` will put your own changes on top of the remote changes. This would probably lead to conflicts, but *YOU* will have to resolve them on your own - not the repo maintainer. Once you have resolved the conflicts, the pull request can be merged without conflicts into the master. But if the pull requests gets not merged immediately and the upstream master gets further developed new changes my arise. You would need to execute the above command again and resolve the conflicts.

Comment: Rebase do NOT avoid conflicts (you could even have more in some specific cases) but let YOU manage the conflicts because that's not the maintainer job. Your job is to ensure that your pull request could be merged without conflicts. In some case,  instead of a rebase, a merge is accepted when you are working with someone else on a pull request (and rewriting history bring too much friction) or when rebasing bring conflicts hard to solve (especially on long running pull request, that you should try to avoid).

Comment: @Philippe You are right! Thanks for your comment. I've added that to my answer.